# React Native: componentWillReceiveProps was deprecated, what should i use to navigate

Tags: react-native, routes, navigation, state

I am using the componentWillReceiveProps to receive the nextstates and navigate to new screen if certain state received.

```
//     if(this.props.success !== prevProps.success && this.props.success) {
//         this.props.navigation.navigate('Attendances');
//     }
//     else if (this.props.error !== prevProps.error && this.props.error) {
//         alert(this.props.errorMessage);
```

Since the new function  GetDerivedStatesFromProps is a static function so I can't use this.props.navigation.navigate to get to next screen.

What or how do I achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use componentDidUpdate:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if(this.props.success !== prevProps.success && this.props.success) {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Attendances');
     } else if (this.props.error !== prevProps.error && this.props.error) {
       alert(this.props.errorMessage);
     }
 }
```

Also I'm not sure why you are calling your method param `prevProps`, since componentWillReceiveProps actually receives the `nextProps`